# FORM: Always appears the error meggage. Why?

Tags: forms, submit

although i receive the email correct the message that appears is the error message. Why is tha happening?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#send").click(function(){
    var name   = $("#name").val();
    var email  = $("#email").val();
    var message  = $("#message").val();   

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url : "contact.php",    
data: "&name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
         success: function(data){    
          if(data == 'success'){
            $("#mail_success").delay(500).fadeIn(500);
            $("#send").attr({"disabled" : "true", "value" : "Message Sent" });
          }else{
            $("#mail_failed").delay(500).fadeIn(500);
            $("#send").attr({"disabled" : "false", "value" : "The Message was not Sent" });

          }     
         }  
       }
      );  
    }
        return true;                      
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that on a successful send, you are REMOVEing the 'disabled' attribute, rather than adding it. Also you should consider using some other tag, and not the 'submit' input type as you are overriding the default behviour.

Answer (score -1):

Technically, `disabled` is not an attribute but a property. So you should not use `removeAttr("disabled")` to enable the button. Use `prop("disabled", false)` instead. To disable the button when it is clicked:

```
$("#send").click(function() {        //When the button is clicked...
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);  //...disable the button.
    ...
```

To display the success message:

```
if(data == 'success') {              //If it was successfull...
    $("#mail_success").fadeIn(500);  //...display the message.
    ...
```

You are also missing a `</div>` right before the `</form>`. Finally, since you are overriding the buttons submit behaviour (as pointed out by @Mark) you should use `<input type="button">` instead of `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: I would appreciate an explanation for the downvote - I would be happy to correct any mistakes.